# How to get shellscript filename without $0?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I tried to use python practice `if __name__ == "__main__":` on shellscript.

Sample scripts are the following:

**a.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="a.sh"

function main() {
  echo "start from $0"
  echo "a.sh is called"
  source b.sh
  bfunc
}

[[ "$0" == "${filename}" ]] && main
```

**b.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="b.sh"

function main() {
  echo "start from $0"
  echo "b.sh is called"
}

function bfunc() {
  echo "hello bfunc"
}

[[ "$0" == "${filename}" ]] && main
```

You can call it with `bash a.sh`.

If you call `bash a.sh`, you'll get like the following:

```
start from a.sh
a.sh is called
hello bfunc
```

Here is my question.
How can I get file name itself without using `$0`?
I don't want to write file name directly, i.e. I want to pass the file name value to `${filename}`.

See the link if you don't know that is the above python practice: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

How can I check wheather `b.sh` is started from command line or was executed by including from `a.sh`?

Comment: side-note: The `function` keyword is superfluous in bash scripts plus it makes your script incompatible with POSIX for no reason. I'd remove it.

Comment: i think, `$0` is the easiest way. Why you don't like it?

Comment: @ViktorKhilin: `$0` refers to the executing program, but he wants to refer to the current file. If the current file is included from another script `$0` will give the wrong result.

Comment: @ViktorKhilin, easiest, but unreliable. See [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the variable `$BASH_SOURCE` to get the name of the current script file.

```
if [[ "$0" == "$BASH_SOURCE" ]]
then
    : "Execute only if started from current script"
else
    : "Execute when included in another script"
fi
```

Comment: You're missing some syntax here; as given, this will try to *run* `$0` (potentially recursing!) with the first argument `==`. Needs to be `[[ "$0" == "$BASH_SOURCE" ]]` or `[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]`.

Comment: Note only the single `=` in the `[` case -- that's because the [POSIX `test` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) only specifies `=` as a string comparison operator; `==` is a nonportable extension... though if you're using `[[`, your code is nonportable anyhow, so it's less of a concern.

Comment: (Also, an `if` or `else` block that contains only a comment isn't valid syntax; you need *some* command, even if it's `true` or its synonym `:`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks, You‘re right, too much Python in mind. I would write an else block only if needed.